# Fill model with fields from document

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I have some `mongo` collection `Cats` with many fields:

```js
[{
_id: 'ObjectId'
param1: 'param1',
param2: 'param2'
}]
```

And i have `nestjs` app where i define schema as:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
  @Prop()
  param1: string;
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Someware in CatService...

```js
  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catModel.find().exec();
  }
```

When i try console log results of request i got all fields, e.g.:

```js
[{
_id: 'ObjectId'
param1: 'param1',
param2: 'param2'
}]
```

Q: How can i get json with only my schema defined fields?
`toJSON` transform?

Answer (score 0):

result of find is an array, you should use `lean()`

```
this.catModel.find({},"-_id -__v").lean()
```

but for `findOne` and `findById` you can use `toObject()` or `toJson()` because the result is an object

```
this.catModel.findById(catID,"-_id -__v").toObject
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Schema({
  versionKey: false,
  toJSON: {
    transform: (doc: Document<Cat>, ret) => {
      ret = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...Object.keys(CatSchema.paths).map((key) => {
          return { [key]: ret[key] };
        }),
      );
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
      return ret;
    },
  },
})
```